# Flatten complex array from Facebook using Azure data factory

Tags: arrays, facebook-graph-api, azure-data-factory

Using the REST connector in Azure Data Factory, I am trying to fetch the Facebook campaign details.
In the pipeline, I have a web activity followed by copy activity. In the mapping section, I can see only the three columns (Id, name, status) from the first array and not getting those columns listed inside the second array.

[graph.facebook.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BsWnV.jpg)

[data factory mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcWEN.jpg)

Is there a way to get the columns listed inside the array? I also tried creating a data flow taking the Json file as source and then used the flatten transformation, still I cannot see the columns related to campaigns. Any help is appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested and find that Data Factory will consider the first object/JSON array as the JSON schema.

If you can adjust the JSON data, then the "insights" can be recognized:
[image]

Schema:

[image]

If you can't, then the "insights" column will be missed:
[image]

In this case, there isn't a way to get all the columns listed inside the array.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Leon Yue for the reply.  Yes, I tried and it worked well when the JSON is modified.  Is there a way JSON file can be transformed in order to get the insights in the first rows? Any suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: @JainThomas You're welcome! No,  there isn't a way that JSON file can be transformed in order to get the insights in the first rows. If my answer is helpful for you, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

@Leon Yue, I found a way to do that.

Step 1: 1.  Copy Facebook campaign data using the REST connector and save as JSON in Azure Blob.

[Step 1: copy activity to extract FB data as JSON and save in Blob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljjF0.png)

Step 2: 2.  Create a Data flow, considering the JSON file from Blob as the source.

[Step 2: Data flow task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWnj1.png)

Step 3: Create a JSON schema and save it in your desktop with the insights array in the first row(which has all the column values) As per your previous comments, I created the JSON schema such that ADF will consider the first object/ JSON array as the JSON schema.

Step 4: In the Data flow - Source dataset, map the JSON schema using the 'Import schema' option from sample file.
[Step 4: Import schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI6JX.png)

Now you will be able to see all the columns from the array.
[All columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBDrc.png)

[Flatten JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Vcy3.png)